# Problem with Windows Server 2008 VHD on Virtual PC2007

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to get WindowsServer2008 up and running on VirtualPC 2007 on my Vista 64 bit.
I've downloaded Windows Server 2008 VHD from the [MSFT site](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=961db8ce-8473-47c2-92eb-b822ec5af0c9&displaylang=en)

WindowsServer instance never comes up.  I see a screen that says "Windows is loading files", and then the instance reboots. This goes in a loop.

Did anyone else get this combination working? Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

If the VHD is packaged for virtual server, it may have the VM additions pre-installed which may be different from what works in Virtual PC. So try booting into safe mode and see if you can un-install them and then re-install the ones that come with Virtual PC2007.

Comment: +1 Reboot-loop sounds like a disk driver issuee...

Answer (score 0):

I have found most of the VHD's work very well (although I haven't tried this exact one)

Have you made sure your general Virtual PC is working fine as expected? Have you done a restart since installing it and/or confirmed it is working by installing another OS or using another VHD?

If you have, then all I suggest is re downloading it from scratch and trying again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=9040a4be-c3cf-44a5-9052-a70314452305&displaylang=en) image, it can't be run using VPC, it requires Hyper-V. Generally saying, it's useless, because to evaluate Windows Server 2008 you need Windows Server 2008.